# Using thread private variables in dynamic DLLs?

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I am looking for some advice about OpenMP. I am confused about the use of threadprivate variables. The problem can be presented in the following example:

```
-----------

// The code below is located the dynamically loaded DLL.
/* Global variable. */
int *p;
#pragma omp threadprivate(p)

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyFunc1(void)
{
  int i;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     MyFunc2(i);
  }
   return TRUE;
}

void MyFunc2(void)
{
    p  = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p  = 0;
    printf(“value = %d”,*p);
    free(p);
}

-----------
```

Here I want each thread to have a separate copy of a global thread-independent variable that will be visible in all functions of the thread. The variable will be initialized and destroyed within the thread.

The “problem” here is that all code including definition of the global variable “p” is located the dynamically loaded DLL (via LoadLibrary).

Microsoft sayshttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z1788dd.aspx: *“You cannot use threadprivate in any DLL that will be loaded via LoadLibrary. This includes DLLs that are loaded with /DELAYLOAD (Delay Load Import), which also uses LoadLibrary.”* So, if I got it right, the above code is not correct – threadprivate variables and dynamically loaded DLL do not mix.

To verify this I created a test project that dynamically loads a DLL add runs a function in parallel using threadprivate as described above. It all worked just fine!

Hmmm ... Now I am confused because that project was not supposed to work.

Can I really use thread private variables in dinamic DLLs or is there a trick to this?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: It didn't work just fine. You expected it to fail, and it didn't fail. Not doing what you expect should never be described as working just fine. You broke the rules and it didn't do what you expected. *That's* what you should have expected in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threadprivate` in the MS OpenMP implementation is translated to `__declspec(thread)` which puts the declared variable in the static TLS (Thread-Local Storage). When a program is started the size of the TLS  is determined by taking into account the TLS size required by the executable as well as the TLS requirements of all other implicitly loaded DLLs. When you load another DLL dynamically with `LoadLibrary` or unload it with `FreeLibrary`, the system has to examine all running threads and to enlarge or compact their TLS storage accordingly. According to [KB118816](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118816):

> This process is too much for operating systems to manage, which can cause an exception either when the DLL is dynamically loaded or code references the data.

Access to such variables is considered undefined behaviour. It works in your case but it doesn't mean that it will work everywhere and every time. [Here](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=187) you can read why exactly it would most likely fail on Windows XP/2003 and earlier Windows versions. According to the same source, implicit TLS handling was rewritten in Windows Vista and so OpenMP `threadprivate` and `__declspec(thread)` should function correctly in run-time loaded DLLs since then. The proposed solution is to use `TlsAlloc` instead.

```
DWORD dwTlsIdx;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyFunc1(void)
{
   int i;
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      MyFunc2(i);
   }
   return TRUE;
}

void MyFunc2(void)
{
    int **pp = (int **)TlsGetValue(dwTlsIdx);
    *pp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **pp  = 0;
    printf(“value = %d”,**pp);
    free(*pp);
}
```

`dwTlsIdx` should be initialised on process attach in `DllMain` with a call to `TlsAlloc`. Enough memory to hold an `int *` should be allocated on thread attach and its address should be set as the value of the `dwTlsIdx` TLS index. Or you could do it in on the first call to `MyFunc2` instead:

```
void MyFunc2(void)
{
    int **pp = (int **)TlsGetValue(dwTlsIdx);
    if (pp == NULL)
    {
       pp = malloc(sizeof(int *));
       TlsSetValue(dwTlsIdx, pp);
    }
    *pp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **pp  = 0;
    printf(“value = %d”,**pp);
    free(*pp);
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details (with error checking).

Comment: I do not see in the mentioned articles anything different from "If there is no enough resources, the function may fail". They do not point to any specific problem. And they do not mention any recent windows version. Code samples in your answers still store data in the same heap. Your calls to `malloc` are prone to failure exactly in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I was not experimenting with OMP, but I have good experience working with

```
DWORD WINAPI TlsAlloc(void);
```

and other `TlsXxx` functions. I am pretty sure that `threadprivate(p)` is a wrapper that ultimately comes to this function. This function works perfectly in exe's, statically and dynamically loaded dll's, etc.

In one case I was seeing about 800 TLS indexes at the same time in my process. Each thread (about 200 threads) was having this number of objects in its thread local storage. NT was allocating buffers in the heap to sore this data. And all this worked fine.

It can be that at the time when the MSDN article was written, there was some problem, but most likely it is fixed now.

My 2 cent.

Comment: Apparently it still causes problems on Windows XP - see [this ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13116).

Answer (score 0):

Hristo and Kirill,

Thank you for the responses.

It appears that Microsoft has fixed  the problem with TLS in dynamic DLL (at least in Windows 7 that I am using). Perhaps they just did not update the documentation. I keep my fingers crossed.

I created a test project where I tested the idea with using TLS via __declspec(thread) pragmas (as Hristo Iliev suggested to me in the other post). The project used large number of TLS variables (just for the sake of testing) and it all worked fine. Then I moved the code in the work project. This is a large project (~1 million lines of code) that loads many dynamic DLLs. It all worked there too.

I am still holding the idea with using TlsAlloc, TlsSetValue, TlsGetValue functions for the worse case scenario.   But it does not fit me well as I am afraid that these functions will add a significant overheard to the number-crunching code that I have. My library needs just a few TLS variables but these variables are used extensively thru the code, including low level functions sitting deep in the stack.

Cheers,

Alex Yamchikov

Comment: You can obtain pointer to the TLS area at the beginning of the parallel region and pass it down the call stack to functions that use thread-private variables. Implicit TLS access also comes at a price - 4 `MOV` instructions in 64-bit mode that implement a stripped down inline version of `TlsGetValue(_tls_index)`.